# How Can I get grep to exit when it is reading input with no EOF

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a shell command that shows me matches in files where an alias is used by my `zsh` shell, however the `grep` portion of the command hangs and forces me to to terminate with a ctrl+c. I assume this happens because `grep` is reading from `stdin` which is an open stream and has no `EOF`.
How can I make this command exit cleanly regardless of the fact that the input piped to grep has no `EOF`?

The command (looking for the origins of the alias ccat):

`zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep ccat`

I know that if you know the number of matches up front you can get it to exit properly using `grep -m1` etc.. but I won't know that before I run the command.

Comment: I tried that command and mine exits cleanly.  (you can specify the end of file in stdin with a ctrl-D)  you may have something unexpected which is causing `grep` not to exit.  Try replacing `grep` with, say, `wc` and see if it exits also.

Comment: "*once stdin has been processed even though there is no EOF*" - what defines "has been processed" in this context, if the stream isn't closed?

Comment: @MarkHeath, thanks looks like its something in **oh-my-zsh**. I tried `wc` and it hung as well: `zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | wc -l` so I tried turning off **oh-my-zsh**, reloaded my shell and both commands now exit cleanly. @dimo414, thanks I edited my question.